# What are the independence and domination numbers of this simple graph G?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Define dom G as the cardinality of the smallest possible subset D of G's vertices such that each of G's vertices is either in D or adjacent to a vertex in D.

Define ind G as the cardinality of the largest possible subset D of G's vertices such that no two vertices in D are adjacent.

(Have I defined dom G and ind G correctly?)

I have worked out dom G and ind G to be both equal to 4, however, I am being given that dom G = 2 and ind G = 3. Please help me understand why this is so.

(For reference, the chromatic and edge chromatic numbers of G are both 4.)

Comment: What are your 'dominating subset' (no idea of the correct name) of size 4 and your independent set of size 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a dominating set of size $2$:

[image]

Note that if you have an independent set, then at most one vertex from the central square can be taken (because all of the vertices of the the central square are adjacent to each other), and no more than two vertices from the outer square can be taken (because the outer square is a cycle of length $4$).  Thus $\mathrm{ind} (G) \leq 3$.  And we can exhibit an independent set of size $3$:

[image]